# Comapring data class in Kotlin using == operator

Tags: kotlin, equals, data-class

I am trying to write an assertion by comparing two Kotlin data classes.I am just simplifying the question by using a minimal class.

```
data class X(val isThatSo: Boolean) {
  val name:String = "xyz"
}
```

In my test

```
val s = """
    {
     "isThatSo": "true",
     "name": "Ankit"
    }
    """

 assert(Gson().fromJson(s, X::class.java) == X(true))
```

Looks to me that the name field is not compared at all because the value in both the objects is different. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html):

> ```
> data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
> ```
>
> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> - `equals()/hashCode()` pair
> - `toString()` of the form "User(name=John, age=42)"
> - `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration.
> - `copy()` function.
>
> To exclude a property from the generated implementations, declare it inside the class body:
>
> ```
> data class Person(val name: String) {
>     var age: Int = 0
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two instances of a class, which are not identical. You can compare the `name` variable within `X` for equality.

Comment: But surprisingly the assertion gives true here

Comment: Why is the name field not getting used while comparing two objects, only the constructor params are getting compared.